# Django Related Manager Add

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-related-manager

I have an intermediate model which is as follows -

```
class Link_Book_Course(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    image = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
    def save(self):
        self.date_created = datetime.now()
        super(Link_Book_Course,self).save()
```

I've created a new Book and a new Link_Book_Course, and am trying to add that book to the Link_Book_Course

call the Link_Book_Course `newCourseLink` and call the Book `newBook`.

I thought that this call would work -

```
newCourseLink.book_set.add(newBook)
```

but Django throws an error saying that newCourseLink has no attribute book_set- does anyone know why?

Furthermore, how can I add the Book to `newCourseLink`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the relationships set up, each `Link_Book_Course` (horrible name, BTW) can only have *one* book. You can't add books, you can only refer to that one book via `newCourseLink.book`.

If you wanted each LBC to have multiple books, the FK should go from Book to LBC.

**Edit after comment** The very point of an intermediate model is that there's one instance of it for every combination of its two FKs. If you want to add new books, you'll need new instances of LBC to go with them. You can *change* the book the current LBC refers to with just `newCourseLink.book = my_new_book`, but as I say you can't add one.

Comment: wait, so how would I keep it as an intermediate model?